# Глючный скролинг в Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-studio

После обновления Android Studio 2.2  скролинг в PreView глючит. Точнее если нажать на ViewAllProperties, то открывается полный список атрибутов.

И если начать скролить, то там такой медленный скроллинг, что просто ужас.

У вас тоже такое же? или это проблема в моей Windows 7?

Comment: Это проблема превью. Тру кодеры не пользуют его из-за таких с ним проблем

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Написал в фидбек гуглу в патче 2.2.1 эту ошибку исправили. Теперь скролиться нормально)